# How to make UIView stop receiving touch events?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitouch, uievent

I'm working on an app where the user is expected to rapidly touch and swipe across multiple UIViews, each of which is supposed to do an action once the user's finger has reached it. I've got *a lot* of views and so the typical thing to do, where I'd iterate over each view to see if a touch is inside of its bounds, is a no-go - there's just too much lag. Is there any other way to get touch events from one view to another (that is beside the first one)? I thought maybe there is some way to cancel the touch event, but I've searched and so far have come up empty.

One of the big problems I have is that if I implement my touch handling in my view controller, touchesBegan only fires for the first touch - if the user touches something and then, without moving the first finger, taps on something else, that tap is not recorded in either touchesBegan or touchesMoved. But if I implement my touch handling in the UIViews themselves, once a view registers a touch, if the user does not lift their finger up and moves it, the views around the first view do not register the touch. Only if the user lifts his finger and then puts it back down will the surrounding views register the touch.

So my question is, lets say I have two views side by side, my touch handling code is implemented in the views, and I put my finger down on view 1. I then slide my finger over to view 2 - what do I need to do to make view 2 register that touch, which started in view 1 and never "ended"?

Answer (score 4):

Set [userInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW50) property of `UIView` to `NO`.

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Tried that, but it does not work.

For example, lets say view 1 detects the touch. It then detects that the touch has moved out of its bounds, so it sets itself userInteractionEnabled = NO; Unfortunately, view 1 keeps receiving touch events (touchesMoved) until the user lifts their finger, while view 2 receives no touch events.

Answer (score 1):

UIView has the following property:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL userInteractionEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what was going on. Thing is, I have my views as subviews of a scrollview, which is itself a subview of my main view. With scrollEnabled = NO, I could touch my subviews - but apparently the scrollview was only forwarding me the initial touch event, and all subsequent touches were part of that initial event. Because of that, I had many weird problems such as touching two views one after the other, both would select and highlight, but if I took the first finger off the screen *both* views would de-select. This was not the desired behavior.

So what I did is I subclassed the scrollview and overrode the touch handling methods to send the events to its first responder, which is its superview, which is the view where I'm doing my touch handling. Now it works!